# Почему не выходит сделать populate?

Tags: node.js, express

Здравствуйте, есть такая схема:

```
title: String,
messages: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Message'
}],
private: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
users: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
```

В модуле хочу получить список пользователей для комнаты. В потоке удаляю из массива пользователей в комнате (users) id пользователя, который зашел. И через populate пытаюсь найти другого пользователя в комнате.

```
async.waterfall([
        function(done){
            var arr = [];
            var stream = Room.find({'$or': [{users: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}, {"private": false}]}).populate('users').lean().stream();

            stream.on('data', function(room){
                delete room.messages;
                room.users.length ? room.users.splice(room.users.indexOf(userId), 1) : null;
                arr.push(room);
                return arr
            });

            stream.on('error', function(err){
            });

            stream.on('close', function(room){
                done(null, arr)
            });
        }
    ],
    function(err,data){
        console.log(data)
        done(null,data)
    });
```

console.log(data) возвращает список комнат, где в каждой

```
users: [ [Object] ]
```

Но при обращении к объекту пользователя console.log(data.users) получаю undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил добавив вывод data.users в середину потока

```
        stream.on('data', function(room){
            delete room.messages;
            room.users.length ? room.users.splice(room.users.indexOf(userId), 1) : null;
            if (room.private === true){
                room.title = room.users[0].email;
            }
            arr.push(room);
            return arr
        });
```